# I want to run exe file that I have created from turbo c in windows 7

Tags: windows-7, exe

I want to run exe file that I have created from turbo c in windows 7. It is a snake game built in C program. The exe file opens in windows xp but not in windows 7. When I tried to open the exe file in windows 7 - it says: Full screen not supported. And cannot be proceed further. What can be done? Please help. Thanks in Advance !!!

The complete code for the snake game is placed in the following blog...
http://nikeshulak.blogspot.com/2013/06/snake-game-revised.html

Comment: Windows is famously compatible with ancient DOS programs, but parts do fall off occasionally.  Video drivers just don't support DOS programs running in full screen graphics mode anymore.  Something you can see by pressing Alt+Enter at a command prompt for example.  The path ahead here is to retire ancient DOS code that just can't run anymore, it belongs in a dusty unseen corner of a museum.

Answer (score 0):

Try running it as an administrator, or by Changing the compatiability mode in Properties, to windows xp mode. This change may work out.

Comment: Thanks Aswin. For your kind help.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply... And Thanks once again. I tried both option you told me. Now it says: Graphics error: Device driver file not found <EGAVGA.BGI> Press any key to halt: But if I opened the file from Turbo C++ or directly in Windows XP such error does not come. And I have EGAVGA.BGI in BGI folder. And when I press Alt + Enter.. It still says: Full screen not supported.

Comment: @nikeshulak the same file `EGAVGA.BGI`, you need to paste near your exe file, then that file should run.